# I am unable to send HTTPS requests from my angular app to my backend

Tags: python, angular, amazon-web-services, api, ssl

I'm currently using AWS for my backend services and angular for the frontend part. Trying to make my website more secure I added a CA signed SSL certificate on my API gateway and added it to my angular website in my angular.json and package.json.

Whenever I try to access the API using CURL from a linux machine providing it with the certificate and key the API returns a reponse however from my Angular website it always returns ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Is there a way to solve this? I'd greatly appreciate any help.

I expected the network layer to be secure and API to return a response. What actually resulted is ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Answer (score 0):

first you must be clarify which webserver use are using Nginx or Apache, if you are using an apache web server then try to correct the SSL [configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) and Nginx [configuration](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/) also in case of using.

But according to me, I think you are also using the **reverse proxy**. First properly configure it. [Learn Apache Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) and [Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

And finally, you can also check the web server log to get the correct error.

Comment: I'm using AWS API gateway

Comment: Please answer the questioner comment.